# Rootless docker with Windows AD auth

Tags: docker, active-directory, rootless

Recently, I began to use docker for my lab's server. The server is a Linux server with Ubuntu server 18.04 installed. Users' login authentication is using Windows **Active Directory** (AD). My  current solution to run non-root docker is by adding users to `docker` group ([ref](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)).

However, I found a severe security problem. AD user `A` can run docker container as any other user `B` by `docker run -u B's uid:B's gid`. In the container, `A` can get all `B`'s permission.

The proper way to run non-root docker may be the newly introduced '[Rootless mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/)', The problem is that rootless mode need newuidmap and newgidmap, but AD users are not listed in /etc/passwd and /etc/subuid etc, which means rootless mode and as well as `userns-remap` mode cannot be used for my situation (i.e. AD auth).

Is there any method to tackle this issue? Thanks so much.
Best.